# How to apply conditional styling (else if) to a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am iterating through a list of header names and I want to change the CSS style of the react component if the name matches one of three conditions. Currently, I have only made this work if it matches the first value but I haven't been able to make it work using a function call.

```
// works for one of the three conditions
  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        {headCells.map((headCell) => (
          < TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            style={headCell.id === 'name' ? { position: 'sticky', left: 55, backgroundColor: 'white' } : {}}
          >
```

I tried to call a function to return the relevant `style`:

```
// 3 conditions
function setHeaderStyle(header: String) {
  if (header === 'name') {
    return { position: 'sticky', left: 55, backgroundColor: 'white' }
  } else if (header === 'totalZ') {
    return { position: 'sticky', right: 0, backgroundColor: 'white' }
  } else {
    return {}
  }
}

// calling above function to style based one 1/3 conditions
{headCells.map((headCell) => (
          < TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            style={setHeaderStyle(headCell.id)}
          >
```

The above function causes the following error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ position: string; left: number; backgroundColor: string; right?: undefined; } | { position: string; right: number; backgroundColor: string; left?: undefined; } | { position?: undefined; left?: undefined; backgroundColor?: undefined; right?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | undefined'.
  Type '{ position: string; left: number; backgroundColor: string; right?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
    Types of property 'position' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Position | undefined'.
  > 228 |             style={setHeaderStyle(headCell.id)}
        |             ^^^^^
```

Comment: That's because `position` in your function is a `string`, but the `Properties` type expects it to be a valid CSS value. Also, please don't use `String` as a type. Use `string` in lowercase. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/what-is-the-difference-between-types-string-and-string) question for why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my comment describes, you have to make the return type of `getHeaderStyle` more specific. One method to achieve that is to use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
function getHeaderStyle(header: string) {
  if (header === 'name') {
    return { position: 'sticky', left: 55, backgroundColor: 'white' } as const
  } else if (header === 'totalZ') {
    return { position: 'sticky', right: 0, backgroundColor: 'white' } as const
  } else {
    return {}
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8LM4w)

Comment: I would suggest to get read of the `as const` assertion and define the returned type from the function as `CSSProperties` in order to keep it more typed-safe.
e.g. : `function getStyle(header: string): CSSProperties`

Comment: Thanks @YarinBarnes, your suggestion made @caTS solution cleaner, although I did need to use `React.CSSProperties` instead of your recommended `CSSProperties`