# What the colon before params list mean in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Giving a piece of code like this:

```js
import React, { FC } from "react";

type GreetingProps = {
  name: string;
}

const Greeting:FC<GreetingProps> = ({ name }) => {
  // name is string!
  return <h1>Hello {name}</h1>
};
```

What is the meaning of the piece `:FC<GreetingProps>`?

If it was `({ name }): Bla`, `Bla` would be the returned value type, but it's not the case here.

**Note**: I know that this way to create a React component With `React.FC` [is discouraged](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-why-i-dont-use-react-fc/), but I just use it as an example to show my Typescript question.

Comment: same, it's just the type of the variable

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#explicit-types

Answer (score 1):

Just like how

```js
const foo: number = 42;
```

is annotating `foo` to be of type `number` (although in this example it's redundant), this code:

```js
const Greeting: FC<GreetingProps> = ({ name }) => {
```

is annotating `Greeting` to be of type `FC<GreetingProps>`. This is so that the props given to the function and the return type are enforced.

Comment: Ok, and if I want to add the return type, is this correct?

```typescript
const Greeting: FC<GreetingProps> = ({ name }): String => {
```

Comment: @FabioPerrella Yes but you should be using lowercase `string`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/what-is-the-difference-between-types-string-and-string) for the differences.

Comment: oh yes, I typed it wrongly, tks