# Use generics with setstate in react js and typescript return string instead of number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to setState onChange event by passing the type of setstate hook.
here is my setState:

```
const [payer, setPayer] = useState<Number>(0);
```

and here is my radio setter:

```
const radioSetter = <T,>(
    e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    setter: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>
  ) => {
    console.log(typeof (e.currentTarget.value as T));
    setter(e.currentTarget.value as T);
  };
```

and this is my input:

```
<input
                      type="radio"
                      name="payer"
                      value={0}
                      checked={payer === 0}
                      onChange={(event) => radioSetter<Number>(event, setPayer)}
                    />
```

the consol log of radioSetter function is string instead of number.
how can i pass the type of setState when calling radioSetter function in onchange event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, use `number` instead of `Number` (see why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/what-is-the-difference-between-types-string-and-string)):

```
const [payer, setPayer] = useState<number>(0);
```

Then use `valueAsNumber` instead of `value`, or convert the string to a number,

```
onChange={(event) => setPayer(event.target.valueAsNumber)}
```

```
onChange={(event) => setPayer(Number(event.target.value))}
```

```
onChange={(event) => setPayer(+event.target.value)}
```

I wouldn't use a function like `radioSetter` since there is no way you can know what type you are supposed to pass to the setter at runtime, and it doesn't seem like it's doing much anyways.

Comment: very important sentence "since there is no way you can know what type you are supposed to pass to the setter at runtime". thank you.