# String or string in TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have misundrestanding in Generics and types
which syntax should i use, and can you explain why ??

```
let myName: String = 'mehran';
console.log(typeof myName);
```

```
let myName: string = 'mehran';
console.log(typeof myName);
```

both log the string type in console and it works correctly

and another example is in generics

```
let arr: Array<String> = []';
```

is Array a constructor function that get an argument and create a array of string type right ???

which syntax should i use ? String or string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/what-is-the-difference-between-types-string-and-string
You may find the answer here

Comment: [Use `string`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html)

Answer (score -1):

`string` in lowercase is the typescript type.
`String` is a javascript class.

In TypeScript use the lowercase `string`

Comment: I see , but why it works correctly for both situations, is String class behind the sence returing string type???