# Typescript shows error when accessing Object variable using a String

Tags: typescript, vue.js

The code below works, but VS Code Typescript compiler shows an error saying **"Type 'String' cannot be used as an index type"**. But if you use a string literal instead of a variable sentence['a-string'] Typescript doesn't complain about that.

I'm happy with the code, but how can I make the error go away? or is there another way to access sentence[display]?

```
const props = defineProps<{
    sentence: Sentence,
    display: String,
}>()
```

```
<div v-html="sentence[display]" />
```

It works, but the Typescript error remains.

Comment: `String` and `string` aren't the same thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/what-is-the-difference-between-types-string-and-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to solve

```
 [key: string]: string;
```

or even you can do `Sentence` interface and add key value inside

```
interface Sentence {
  [key: string]: string; // Allows indexing with a string key to get a string value.
}
```

Also as @Estus Flask said, string and String arent the same thing

```
  const props = defineProps<{
    sentence: Sentence,
    display: string,
}>()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try telling typescript the object can be indexed by strings like

```
const props = defineProps<{
    [key:string]:any, /* or whatever type you expect */
    sentence: Sentence,
    display: String,
}>()
```

Comment: It's sentence and not props that's accessed by index

Comment: hey man this works, but I don't understand why it works. I guess I need to study Typescript.

Comment: the error you get is due to that typescript does not know, how to index the props
hence 
"Type 'String' cannot be used as an index type".

[key:string]:any
this only tells typescript the this object can be indexed bay any string, and values will be any

Answer (score 0):

You can  declare `display` as a key of `Sentence`:

```
const props = defineProps<{
    sentence: Sentence,
    display: keyof Sentence,
}>()
```

This will give you error messages when you pass a wrong value to `display` and allow your IDE to suggest values.

---

If `Sentence` does not have fixed keys (i.e. `type Sentence = {[key: string]: any}`, but the keys of a concrete object can be inferred, you can use generics to nail down the concrete keys:

```html
<script setup lang="ts" generic="O extends Sentence">

const props = defineProps<{
    sentence: O
    display: keyof O
}>()
```

With this, you again get errors when the `display` value does not match one of the keys of the object.

One caveat: Vue currently cannot infer the correct type in templates, i.e. writing `{{ sentence[display] }}` in the template gives an error. But you can use a computed to get around it.